# Java parse contents of a string into lines, auto-detecting line type

Tags: java, newline, text-parsing

I have a string of around a hundred lines, it is unknown whether the lines will be "\r\n" or "\n".

I want to parse the string once, processing each line.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096621/how-to-read-a-string-line-per-line) almost answers mine, but there's no mention of how to deal with unknown new line delimiting characters.

I was thinking of using one of the above methods, choosing "\n" as the delimiter and then stripping any "\r" characters on a line-by-line basis.

While performance really isn't an issue, I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way of doing this. I have not been able to find any methods that automatically handle line delimiter types.

**Attempt #1, as per suggestion from @TritonMan:**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myString);
String line = scanner.nextLine();
// line contains whole contents of string, not just the first line
```

If it matters, I am running this on Android. The string comes from a PLS file (playlist) which doesn't seem to be well defined anywhere, so I do not know what type of line delimiters it uses.

As a fallback, I will use the code from this question, but it's now bugging me how to do it without regex or `String.split()` in case I deal with streams:

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Comment: Does the second answer not work for you?  It should.  The one that uses Scanner

Comment: It didn't work - please see my edit

Comment: Scanner and BufferedReader don't care about the type of line ending. They will match both of them. [See also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259411/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-java-string/9259462#9259462)

Comment: Thanks - turns out (as you probably knew) I did not notice that other code stripped out the lines before passing it to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : JDK is open source! You can look how the `Scanner` class is implemented.

In short:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(source);

while(in.hasNextLine())
    String line = in.nextLine();

    //Do something!
```

will store a line on both `"\r\n"` and `"\n"` cases.