# Read multiple .txt files and write information to an Array

Tags: java

I have a method that creates files containing the name and age and writes, Example "name.txt" and the content is .. name-age .. would like to get this information from 10 .txt files and write in a single file, line after line

Comment: use file append concept when you finished writing from a file and loop through all files.

Answer (score 1):

You can [iterate through files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917326/how-to-iterate-over-the-files-of-a-certain-directory-in-java) inside a directory. In each file you can [iterate through lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259411/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-java-string) and print them out.